# Know of a Rails 2.3 migration cheat sheet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting started with Ruby on Rails. I think some cheat sheets or reference cards would really help me to get started (specifically, with migrations).

Do you know of any cheat sheets or reference cards that would help me get started?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Too obvious? http://appletree.or.kr/quick_reference_cards/Ruby-Ruby_on_Rails/rails-migrations.pdf

<strike>http://dizzy.co.uk/ruby_on_rails/cheatsheets/rails-migrations</strike> (no longer available)

<strike>Same cheatsheet available here: http://appletree.or.kr/quick_reference_cards/ruby-ruby%20on%20rails/rails-migrations.pdf</strike>

Comment: Link is no longer correct (looks like dizzy.co.uk is now a parked domain).

Comment: Another copy: http://appletree.or.kr/quick_reference_cards/ruby-ruby%20on%20rails/rails-migrations.pdf

Comment: and a new one: http://appletree.or.kr/quick_reference_cards/Ruby-Ruby_on_Rails/rails-migrations.pdf

Answer (score 3):

[cheat.errtheblog.com](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/) installs as gem and you can search from the command line.

[Here's the cheat for migrations](http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rails_migrations/).

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/ActiveRecord/Migrations